# Filebeat: Failed to start crawler: starting input failed: Error while initializing input: Can only start an input when all related states are finished

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, filebeat

I have a job that starts several docker containers periodically and for each container I also start a filebeat docker container to gather the logs and save them in elastic search.
Filebeat version 7.9 has been used.
Docker containers are started from java application using spotify docker client and terminated when job finishes.
The filebeat configuration is the following and it monitors only a specific docker container:

```
 filebeat.inputs:

  - paths: ${logs_paths}
    include_lines: ['^{']
    json.message_key: log
    json.keys_under_root: true
    json.overwrite_keys: true
    json.add_error_key: true
    type: log
    scan_frequency: 10s
    ignore_older: 15m

  - paths: ${logs_paths}
    exclude_lines: ['^{']
    json.message_key: log
    type: log
    json.keys_under_root: true
    json.overwrite_keys: true
    json.add_error_key: true
    scan_frequency: 10s
    ignore_older: 15m
    max_bytes: 20000000

processors:
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["log"]
      target: ""

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ${elastic_host}
  username: "something"
  password: "else"

logs_paths:
  - /var/lib/docker/containers/40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5/40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5-json.log
```

From time to time we observe that one filebeat container is crashing immediately after starting with the following error. Although the job runs the same docker images each time, the filebeat error might appear to any of them:

```
2020-12-09T16:00:15.784Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:640    Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Data path: [/usr/share/filebeat/data] Logs path: [/usr/share/filebeat/logs]
2020-12-09T16:00:15.864Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:648    Beat ID: 03ef7f54-2768-4d93-b7ca-c449e94b239c
2020-12-09T16:00:15.868Z    INFO    [seccomp]   seccomp/seccomp.go:124  Syscall filter successfully installed
2020-12-09T16:00:15.868Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:976    Beat info   {"system_info": {"beat": {"path": {"config": "/usr/share/filebeat", "data": "/usr/share/filebeat/data", "home": "/usr/share/filebeat", "logs": "/usr/share/filebeat/logs"}, "type": "filebeat", "uuid": "03ef7f54-2768-4d93-b7ca-c449e94b239c"}}}
2020-12-09T16:00:15.869Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:985    Build info  {"system_info": {"build": {"commit": "b2ee705fc4a59c023136c046803b56bc82a16c8d", "libbeat": "7.9.0", "time": "2020-08-11T20:11:11.000Z", "version": "7.9.0"}}}
2020-12-09T16:00:15.869Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:988    Go runtime info {"system_info": {"go": {"os":"linux","arch":"amd64","max_procs":4,"version":"go1.14.4"}}}
2020-12-09T16:00:15.871Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:992    Host info   {"system_info": {"host": {"architecture":"x86_64","boot_time":"2020-10-28T10:03:29Z","containerized":true,"name":"638de114b513","ip":["someIP"],"kernel_version":"4.4.0-190-generic","mac":["someMAC"],"os":{"family":"redhat","platform":"centos","name":"CentOS Linux","version":"7 (Core)","major":7,"minor":8,"patch":2003,"codename":"Core"},"timezone":"UTC","timezone_offset_sec":0}}}
2020-12-09T16:00:15.876Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1021   Process info    {"system_info": {"process": {"capabilities": {"inheritable":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"permitted":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"effective":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"bounding":["chown","dac_override","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","net_bind_service","net_raw","sys_chroot","mknod","audit_write","setfcap"],"ambient":null}, "cwd": "/usr/share/filebeat", "exe": "/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat", "name": "filebeat", "pid": 1, "ppid": 0, "seccomp": {"mode":"filter"}, "start_time": "2020-12-09T16:00:14.670Z"}}}
2020-12-09T16:00:15.876Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:299    Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 7.9.0
2020-12-09T16:00:15.876Z    INFO    [index-management]  idxmgmt/std.go:184  Set output.elasticsearch.index to 'someIndex' as ILM is enabled.
2020-12-09T16:00:15.877Z    INFO    eslegclient/connection.go:99    elasticsearch url: someURL
2020-12-09T16:00:15.878Z    INFO    [publisher] pipeline/module.go:113  Beat name: 638de114b513
2020-12-09T16:00:15.885Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:118  Starting metrics logging every 30s
2020-12-09T16:00:15.886Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:450    filebeat start running.
2020-12-09T16:00:15.893Z    INFO    memlog/store.go:119 Loading data file of '/usr/share/filebeat/data/registry/filebeat' succeeded. Active transaction id=0
2020-12-09T16:00:15.893Z    INFO    memlog/store.go:124 Finished loading transaction log file for '/usr/share/filebeat/data/registry/filebeat'. Active transaction id=0
2020-12-09T16:00:15.893Z    INFO    [registrar] registrar/registrar.go:108  States Loaded from registrar: 0
2020-12-09T16:00:15.893Z    INFO    [crawler]   beater/crawler.go:71    Loading Inputs: 2
2020-12-09T16:00:15.894Z    INFO    log/input.go:157    Configured paths: [/var/lib/docker/containers/40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5/40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5-json.log]
2020-12-09T16:00:15.895Z    INFO    [crawler]   beater/crawler.go:141   Starting input (ID: 3906827571448963007)
2020-12-09T16:00:15.895Z    INFO    log/harvester.go:297    Harvester started for file: /var/lib/docker/containers/40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5/40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5-json.log
2020-12-09T16:00:15.902Z    INFO    beater/crawler.go:148   Stopping Crawler
2020-12-09T16:00:15.902Z    INFO    beater/crawler.go:158   Stopping 1 inputs
2020-12-09T16:00:15.902Z    INFO    [crawler]   beater/crawler.go:163   Stopping input: 3906827571448963007
2020-12-09T16:00:15.902Z    INFO    input/input.go:136  input ticker stopped
2020-12-09T16:00:15.902Z    INFO    log/harvester.go:320    Reader was closed: /var/lib/docker/containers/40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5/40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5-json.log. Closing.
2020-12-09T16:00:15.902Z    INFO    beater/crawler.go:178   Crawler stopped
2020-12-09T16:00:15.902Z    INFO    [registrar] registrar/registrar.go:131  Stopping Registrar
2020-12-09T16:00:15.902Z    INFO    [registrar] registrar/registrar.go:165  Ending Registrar
2020-12-09T16:00:15.903Z    INFO    [registrar] registrar/registrar.go:136  Registrar stopped
2020-12-09T16:00:15.912Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:153  Total non-zero metrics  {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":80,"time":{"ms":80}},"total":{"ticks":230,"time":{"ms":232},"value":0},"user":{"ticks":150,"time":{"ms":152}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1048576},"open":8},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"cae44857-494c-40e7-bf6a-e06e2cf40759","uptime":{"ms":290}},"memstats":{"gc_next":16703568,"memory_alloc":8518080,"memory_total":40448184,"rss":73908224},"runtime":{"goroutines":11}},"filebeat":{"events":{"added":2,"done":2},"harvester":{"closed":1,"open_files":0,"running":0,"started":1}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"output":{"type":"elasticsearch"},"pipeline":{"clients":0,"events":{"active":0,"filtered":2,"total":2}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":1,"update":2},"writes":{"success":2,"total":2}},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":4},"load":{"1":1.79,"15":1.21,"5":1.54,"norm":{"1":0.4475,"15":0.3025,"5":0.385}}}}}}
2020-12-09T16:00:15.912Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:154  Uptime: 292.790204ms
2020-12-09T16:00:15.912Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:131  Stopping metrics logging.
2020-12-09T16:00:15.913Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:456    filebeat stopped.
2020-12-09T16:00:15.913Z    ERROR   instance/beat.go:951    Exiting: Failed to start crawler: starting input failed: Error while initializing input: Can only start an input when all related states are finished: {Id: native::4096794-64769, Finished: false, Fileinfo: &{40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5-json.log 0 416 {874391692 63743126415 0x608b880} {64769 4096794 1 33184 0 0 0 0 0 4096 0 {1607529615 874391692} {1607529615 874391692} {1607529615 874391692} [0 0 0]}}, Source: /var/lib/docker/containers/40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5/40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5-json.log, Offset: 0, Timestamp: 2020-12-09 16:00:15.896210395 +0000 UTC m=+0.302799924, TTL: -1ns, Type: log, Meta: map[], FileStateOS: 4096794-64769}
Exiting: Failed to start crawler: starting input failed: Error while initializing input: Can only start an input when all related states are finished: {Id: native::4096794-64769, Finished: false, Fileinfo: &{40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5-json.log 0 416 {874391692 63743126415 0x608b880} {64769 4096794 1 33184 0 0 0 0 0 4096 0 {1607529615 874391692} {1607529615 874391692} {1607529615 874391692} [0 0 0]}}, Source: /var/lib/docker/containers/40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5/40c453871c01f0581b832e0452659553b6be2ac4dc1ac8bfaf2b5478bca1cec5-json.log, Offset: 0, Timestamp: 2020-12-09 16:00:15.896210395 +0000 UTC m=+0.302799924, TTL: -1ns, Type: log, Meta: map[], FileStateOS: 4096794-64769}
```

Does anyone have an idea what might cause this?

Comment: You have two filebeat inputs reading from the same log, you can't have multiple inputs reading from the same log file, you need to remove one of your inputs.